# Changing a user password through phpMyAdmin

Tags: 7, users, database

Hopefully this should be a quickly resolvable query:

If I only have phpMyAdmin as a means of changing a password - e.g. say I can't login and need to change the Admin password (and Drush is equally not available etc) should I be able to reset a user's password using the following query:

```
UPDATE drupal_users SET pass = SHA2( 'the_password', 256 ) WHERE uid = 20
```

where the drupal tables are prefixed with "drupal_"

I have tried the above query in order to change the password for a user, but when using the password specified in the above sql statement I am still unable to login.  This makes me think I am missing something here.

Anyone got any ideas how to change a drupal 7 user password via PhpMyAdmin using SQL?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/1023428

Comment: You can generate the query [here](http://btobac.com/change-admin-password-drupal-password-generator) & run the query in your database.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal 7 uses a hash salt (see your settings.php) in addition to several other bit of information in order to create a SHA2 of the users PW. You should really use drush to change a user's pw if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

If you have some other Drupal user account access to the site with enough rights, you can generate new hash as follows: Create any content page with PHP text format and put there:

```
<?php
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . variable_get('password_inc', 'includes/password.inc');
print('Hash: ' . user_hash_password('my_password'));
?>
```

Otherwise, if we don't have any Drupal user access or file access I am afraid we are in trouble, because the hash salt is stored in the config file.

Comment: If you’re bootstrapped far enough to use variable_get wouldn’t you just update the relevant user entity at this point too? Otherwise it’s still a manual job to get it into the database

Comment: You are right, but, as far as I understand, we've got phpMyAdmin, so I wouldn't bother to write the code for DB update risking to mess up the user table.

Comment: I meant with user_load/user_save. Manipulating entity data directly is not a smart move unless you really know what you’re doing and what the risks are

Comment: That would definitely be an option, I agree. But, anyway, the main question is if we have any other access besides phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Agreed. I think "don't do that, use the API instead" is a valid response though, even if we don't know for sure the OP has other means of access. Try to save people from themselves and all that...

Comment: Thanks for providing a potential solution Krill Shabunov and to Clive for your input.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a local version with the same setting.php / salt hash, you can use the password-hash script.  This will generate a new hashed password that can be inserted via SQL.

All this is explained in the [docs](https://www.drupal.org/node/1023428).